# What permissions should .htaccess have?

Tags: .htaccess, permissions

I am working on pinnacle cart - but the thing is that when i am trying to set "Enable flat URLs generation", it says:

> Please note: Error writing '.htaccess' file. Please check file permissions.

I am not sure which permission it should be. I know it need to have mod_rewrite working as well. I am not familiar with .htaccess and mod_rewrite.

chmod 644 .htacesss doesn't work at all. So I am guessing if i don't do anything with mod_rewrite, then .htaccess isnt working?

i did: 
chown root .htaccess 
chown 644 .htaccess

example:

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /
RewriteCond     $1 !^(\#(.)*|\?(.)*|\.buildpath(.)*|.svn\/(.)*|admin\.php(.)*|content\/(.)*|download\.php(.)*|images\/(.)*|index\.php(.)*|install\/(.)*|login\.php(.)*|readme\.txt(.)*|robots\.txt(.)*)
RewriteRule     ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

One problem is that it will cause the .html to be down online. so **do i have to add "`*|home\.html(.)*`"**?

Please give me insight on this and thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chown` the file(.htaccess) to set the owner to PHP's user, then `chmod 755` That should do the trick :)

Plus you want: `RewriteEngine On` see below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(#(.)|\?(.)|.buildpath(.)|.svn\/(.)|admin.php(.)|content\/(.)|download.php(.)|images\/(.)|index.php(.)|install\/(.)|login.php(.)|readme.txt(.)|robots.txt(.)*)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: PHP's user? did you mean root? Sorry I am not too familiar with terminology. I did turn rewriteEngine on but .html is down. So i am guessing that I need to add in .html?

Comment: @Josephine: No, not `root`. `root` should have absolutely nothing to do with this. PHP's usergroup is possibly `webuser` and it'll be running as `apache` in most cases. So I'd `chown apache:webuser .htaccess; chmod 755 .htaccess` to give write access to the Apache user.